# What does an Object created on the stack contain?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, memory-management, stack

Let's say I create an object without using the new operator like this :

```
Object b;
```

I am using the default constructor of my Object Class. Say that this class gives the object an attribute
`int objectID;` .
I know I can manipulate my object by doing b.Display() for instance if I have defined a Display() method. I know that when I create my object that way it and it's attributes are stored on the stack.

**But what I don't understand is what does `b`  contain exactly?**

(I know that if I had created by object this way  `Object * b = new Object;`  b would point to the attribute objectID that would be stored on the heap.)

Thanks!

Comment: In the second example`b` is a pointer to the object. I don't exactly understand what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking about the first example. The second example I understand. I'll rephrase : in the first example with Object b; what value is stored inside of b?

Comment: The `Object` is what is in `b`

Comment: Think of it this way: `new` gives an address in the heap, while the stack is accessed by distances to its top or bottom. Otherwise, contents are the same.

Comment: "_I know that when I create my object that way it and it's attributes are stored on the stack._" 1) Technically - the C++ standard doesn't force the compiler to use the stack at all. It just defines "Automatic variable storage", and requirements on that. Stack is just an implementation detail. 2) Technically#2: without [mre], it's impossible to tell whether it will be allocated on "stack", since it depends where such variable is declared. For example: If it's a global variable, it won't be allocated in "stack".

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Ok, but how come in **the second example** b points to **first attribute of the object** (meaning objectID)? It doesn't point to the object. I guess my question is not very clear. 
**In the first example** b contains the object. But the object is essentially an int objectID. Does that mean that b contains an int?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Sorry I was imprecise. I create the object in the main function.

Comment: `b` contains an `Object`.  You then access it's members with `.`.  *but how come in the second example b points to first attribute of the object (meaning objectID)?* This only applies to *standard layout classes*.  If your class is not standard layout then the pointer doesn't necessarily point to the first member.  The pointer points to the `Object`.

Comment: `b` ***is*** an `Object`. It contains all the stuff that an `Object` contains. I don't really understand why you would need to ask.

Comment: @user253751 I am doing an exercise where I need to represent the memory management of a main function where I create an object. I was confused on how to represent my object b as it is not a pointer. I didn't know if I should just represent the object's attributes or represent a case "b" that would point to the attributes...

Comment: @CSstudZ "_I was confused on how to represent my object b as it is not a pointer._" You can still get a pointer to `b`, if it's "on stack": `Object* pb = &b;`

Answer (score 0):

It contains exactly the same data that would be stored on the heap if you allocated an `Object` on the heap: Member variables, padding, vtable pointers, base classes, and anything else I've forgotten. Since this is an exercise where you have to draw the memory layout, I assume `Object` doesn't have any virtual functions or base classes, so it will just be the member variables and possibly padding.